# Colored output on bash script for smartctl

Tags: bash, colors

After reading several topics, I managed to get my simple smartctl script working for displaying SMART information about the harddisks behind a 3WARE RAID controller.

Thanks to Emily E. it now outputs the broken harddisk in red. However it will  color all drives in the array (with the broken drive) red, instead of singling out only the broken harddisk.

This is what I have in the script so far (updated thanks to Emily E.):

```
bold=$(tput bold)
red=$(tput setaf 1)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
normal=$(tput sgr0)

echo "${green}${bold}:: CONTROLLER POORT 0 - HARDDISK ARRAY A (22x) ::${normal}"
out0=$(
for i in {0..21}; do
    echo -en '\n'
    echo "HARDDISK $i" $SN $MD
    smartctl -i -A /dev/twa0 -d 3ware,$i |grep -E "^  "5"|^"197"|^"198"|"FAILING_NOW"|"Serial"|"Smartctl""
done
)
if echo "$out0" | grep -q "Device Read Identity Failed"; then
  echo "$red$out0"
else
  echo "$out0"
fi

echo -en '\n'
echo -en '\n'

echo "${green}${bold}:: CONTROLLER POORT 1 - HARDDISK ARRAY B (22x) :::${normal}"
out1=$(
for i in {0..21}; do
    echo -en '\n'
    echo "HARDDISK $i" $SN $MD
    smartctl -i -A /dev/twa1 -d 3ware,$i |grep -E "^  "5"|^"197"|^"198"|"FAILING_NOW"|"Serial"|"Smartctl""
done
)

if echo "$out1" | grep -q "Device Read Identity Failed"; then
  echo "$red$out1"
else
  echo "$out1"
fi

echo -en '\n'
echo -en '\n'

echo "${green}${bold}:: CONTROLLER POORT 1 - HARDDISK ARRAY OS (2x) :::${normal}"
out2=$(
for i in {0..1}; do
    echo -en '\n'
    echo "HARDDISK $i" $SN $MD
    smartctl -i -A /dev/twa2 -d 3ware,$i |grep -E "^  "5"|^"197"|^"198"|"FAILING_NOW"|"Serial"|"Smartctl""
done
)
if echo "$out2" | grep -q "Device Read Identity Failed"; then
  echo "$red$out2"
else
  echo "$out2"
fi
echo -en '\n'
```

With the new/updated code, it now colors things red, but also the complete array, instead of just one drive. Maybe there is a workaround for that?

If not, I will leave it as it is. But it would be easier to notice when only the broken disk was colored red, instead of the complete array.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I want the result of the output of smartctl to be red when it matches "Smartctl: Device Read Identity Failed: Input/output error"

I don't know how to explain it better than this?

Answer (score 1):

Write like this

```
out=$( smartctl ... )
if echo "$out" | grep -q "Device Read Identity Failed"; then
  echo "$red$out"
else
  echo "$out"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out. I used the provided code you provided and adjusted it a little. It works (almost), but instead of coloring only the broken drive, it colors the whole array red. Is this fixable? If not, or to much work. Leave it as it is. I appreciate the help. FYI: I have updated my main post including the new code. Maybe it provides some better insight. TY.